Pattern matching an array of n items
I'm testing a model in rails, and I'd like to assert that one of the associations has an n items. I've found that the assert_pattern matcher is a pretty good way to do it:
assert_pattern do
  author.books.to_a =>
    [Book,
    Book,
    Book,
    Book,
    Book]
end

However, I've also found that having a big list of items like that can be difficult to read. I've tried expanding the array the way I usually would in ruby:
assert_pattern do
  author.books.to_a => [Book]*5
end

However, within a pattern matcher, that's a syntax error:
test/models/book_test.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting `end' or dummy end (SyntaxError)
    author.books.to_a => [Book]*5
                               ^

Is there a concise way to make a pattern that's a function of length?

It's hard to understand why you're using pattern matching for this. What's wrong with author.books.count(Book) == 5? Or if you want to reify a specific array of Book objects as a comparator, then author.books == Array.new(5, Book) should be true if author.books #=> [Book, Book, Book, Book, Book].

@ToddA.Jacobs even that's a very roundabout way of doing assert_equal(5, author.books.count).

@spickermann That's a syntax error as well. The * doesn't appear to be a legal token inside a pattern.

@ToddA.Jacobs That's a very reasonable answer to this in practice, but it's a less thorough test, is less fun, and isn't what I asked.

@max assert_equal(5, author.books.count) only asserts that the authors.books Array has exactly five members. That's not really what the OP is asking for; my answer was addressing his question about matching against a specific count of particular objects (in this case, Books) in an Array. He could use the finder pattern, but first he has to solve for incorrectly creating an Array of five Books.

@ToddA.Jacobs note that the array is most likely an array of Book instances though, not an array containing the Book class 5 times.

@Stefan Possibly so, but this is why No MCVE is a thing. Guessing at people's programming intent or actual data structures just wastes everyone's time. You gave a good answer below; whether it fixes the OP's actual problem or whether the whole thing is an X/Y problem because the OP considers it less fun is an open question at the moment.


Is there a concise way to make a pattern that's a function of length?

I don't think so. Although you can use arbitrary expressions inside a pattern via ^(expression), the matching is quite different.
When using the literal [pattern, ..., *variable] syntax, e.g.:
ary => [Foo, Bar, Baz]

Ruby will first check that ary has a length of 3 and then match each element individually like this:

Foo === ary[0]
Bar === ary[1]
Baz === ary[2]

For classes or modules, this is equivalent to an is_a? check.
Note that in the example above, [Foo, Bar, Baz] isn't an actual array. Pattern matching just uses an array-like syntax. Within this syntax, you can also use * as a wildcard or bind values to variables.

When using the ^(expression) syntax, e.g.:
ary => ^([Foo, Bar, Baz])

Ruby will treat the result of that expression as a single value and just perform one check:

[Foo, Bar, Baz] === ary

Apparently, that won't work in your case as comparing both arrays via === isn't equivalent to checking each element individually:
[Book, Book] === [Book.new, Book.new] #=> false

You could construct an array or matcher object that has custom === behavior. But at that point, it would probably be easier to use a simple assertion instead of pattern matching, e.g.:
assert do
  author.books.count == 5 && author.books.to_a.all?(Book)
end

(the type check might be superfluous unless you are dealing with a polymorphic association or STI)
